# Give $\mathbb{R}$ the floor topology. Is every point of $\mathbb{R}$ a limit point of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Question is: Give $\mathbb{R}$ the floor topology. Is every point of $\mathbb{R}$ a limit point of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

This is how I did it, is this correct? 
It would be great if somebody checks my proof and tells me if I am correct or wrong. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma.....Can you please check this? If you think there is something wrong or you need to add it, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $O$ is open in the "floor topology" and contains $x$, then there is some $y>x$ such that $x \in [x,y) \subseteq O$, by the definition of its base. (you could start by saying that we have some $x \in [x_a,y_a)$ with the property but then $[x,y_a)$ also does, so we can have left point equal to $x$ WLOG).

Then we can find $y'$ with $x < y' < y$ (e.g. $y'=\frac{x+y}{2}$ will do, but the algebra is not really needed, the fact there are reals stricly between any two reals is quite standard), and then $y' \in O\setminus \{x\}$ and so $x$ is a limit point of $\Bbb R$ (so there are no isolated points in $\Bbb R$ in the floor topology).

This observation is all that is required.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, taking a look at my proof, do u think there is something which I missed or didn’t mention?? I’m guessing that my proof looks good.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun You're making it too complicated, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology, $x$ is a limit point of $A\subset X$ if and only if for all $U\in\mathcal{B}$ with $x\in U$, $U\cap A\setminus \{x\}\neq\emptyset$.

In particular, given $x\in \mathbb{R}$, if $x\in [a,b)$, then $a\le x< b$. Choose any $y\in (x,b)$. Then $[a,b)$ contains a point different from $x$, and we're done.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but here we have floor or lower limit topology. Lower limit topology is the topology generated by basis $B_{ll}$ : = {[a,b) | a < b $\in$ X}. For this, how should I show that every point of Reals are a limit point of Reals?

Comment: The argument I gave in the answer shows exactly that.

Comment: I totally understand this, however can you give a general example which shows that for a set of Reals, if they have floor topology, then all the points of R will be a limit point of R? That will help me understand this better.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun The question is *only* is every $x \in \Bbb R$ a limit point of $\Bbb R$ in the floor topology, or otherwise put: does $\Bbb R$ have an isolated point in this topology? It's not about arbitrary subsets.